# How do I demoralize more often?

Tags: skills, pathfinder-2e

So I recently picked up the PF-2e core book, and I noticed that Intimidate as a skill has a lot more built-in support than it had in PF-1e, having both rogue *and* fighter feats dedicated to it in the core book, specifically, the Demoralize use of Intimidate.

**Demoralize:**

> With a sudden shout, a well-timed taunt, or a cutting put-down, you can shake an enemy’s resolve. Choose a creature within 30 feet of you who you’re aware of. Attempt an Intimidation check against that target’s Will DC. If the target does not understand the language you are speaking, you’re not speaking a language, or they can’t hear you, you take a –4 circumstance penalty to the check. Regardless of your result, the target is temporarily immune to your attempts to Demoralize it for 10 minutes.
>
> **Critical Success**: The target becomes frightened 2.
> **Success**: The target becomes frightened 1.

This support, coupled with the fact that demoralizing a target is more useful overall, and the effects even stacking if multiple people pile on intimidates to the same target, makes an intimidate build quite appealing. The only problem I noticed was this line here

> Regardless of your result, the target is temporarily immune to your attempts to Demoralize it for 10 minutes.

So whenever you attempt demoralize someone with intimidate, pass or fail, it has an effective 10 minute cool-down before you can do it to that target again, which could put a serious damper on an Intimidate-build characters combat effectiveness if they fail and can't try again.

**To remedy this weakness, are there any feats or magical trinkets that one can acquire to reduce/remove this period of not being able to demoralize the same target?**

Comment: One small note, Frightened doesn't stack, it just takes the highest.  The number of rounds spent Frightened can definitely be increased by multiple people contributing though, provided they wait for the last one to fall off before doing the next :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Archives of Nethys (https://2e.aonprd.com/) is the official online source for Pathfinder information. They have a [search](https://2e.aonprd.com/Search.aspx?query=demoralize) function you may get some use out of.

---

### Only one ability seems to remove the immunity to Demoralize

[Braggart](https://2e.aonprd.com/Styles.aspx?ID=2) Swashbucklers (Advanced Player's Guide) can at level 9

When such a Swashbuckler performs a [Finisher](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=322) attack, they gain this benefit from Exemplary Finisher

> If the foe was temporarily immune to your Demoralize, their temporary immunity ends.

This affect is unavailable to Swashbuckler Multiclass, so you would have to select Swashbuckler as your actual class.

### There are other sources of Frightened, if that's what you're after

(This list was exhaustive, to the extent of my knowledge, at the time of writing but is not intended to be a full reference for such features)

Feat (Intimidation Skill) - [Scare to Death](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=837)

> Attempt an Intimidation check against the Will DC...
> **Critical Success** The target must succeed at a Fortitude save against your Intimidation DC or die. If the target succeeds at its save, it becomes frightened 2 and is fleeing for 1 round; it suffers no effect on a critical success.
> **Success** The target becomes frightened 2.
> **Failure** The target becomes frightened 1.

Feat, Stance (Monk, Martial Artist Archetype) - [Dragon Roar](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=451&ArchLevel=8)

> **Prerequisites** Dragon Stance **Requirements** You are in Dragon Stance. **Effect** You bellow, instilling fear in your enemies. Enemies within a 15-foot emanation must succeed at a Will save against your Intimidation DC or be frightened 1 (frightened 2 on a critical failure). [...] Creatures in the area of your roar are then temporarily immune for 1 minute.

[Marshal](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=66) Archetype - [Dread Marshal Stance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2006)

> **Critical Success** Your marshal's aura increases to a 20-foot emanation, and it grants you and allies a status bonus to damage rolls equal to the number of weapon damage dice of the unarmed attack or weapon you are wielding that has the most weapon damage dice. When you or an ally in the aura critically hits an enemy with a Strike, that enemy is frightened 1.
> **Success** As critical success, but your aura's size doesn't increase.

Spell (Wizard Focus, [Feat](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=647) for Enchantment School) - [Dread Aura](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=526)*

> **Cast** [Two Actions] somatic, verbal; **Area** 30-foot-radius emanation centered on you; **Duration** sustained up to 1 minute. You emit an aura of terror. Foes in the area are frightened 1 and unable to reduce the condition.

Spell (Bard Focus, [Feat](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=192)) - [Dirge of Doom](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=382)*

> **Cast** [Single Action] verbal; **Area** 30-foot emanation; **Duration** 1 round. Foes within the area are frightened 1. They can't reduce their frightened value below 1 while they remain in the area.

Spell (Witch (APG) Cantrip for [Curse](https://2e.aonprd.com/Patrons.aspx?ID=2) Patron Theme) - [Evil Eye](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=798)

> **Cast** [Single Action] somatic; **Range** 30 feet; **Targets** 1 creature; **Saving Throw** Will; **Duration** sustained up to 1 minute. [...]The target becomes frightened based on the results of its Will save. This condition value can't be reduced below 1 while the spell is active and you can see the target. Regardless of the outcome, the target is then temporarily immune for 1 minute.
> **Failure** The target is frightened 1.
> **Critical Failure** The target is frightened 2.

Item - [Dread Blindfold](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=433)

> The first time a particular creature sees you in a day, it must succeed at a DC 37 Will save or be frightened 1. This is an emotion, fear, and mental effect, and your allies become immune to it after about a week.

Item - [Gorget of the Primal Roar](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=439) (this is an Intimidation check, not a Demoralize attempt)

> **Activate** [Single Action] command; **Frequency** once during the duration of each polymorph effect; **Requirements** You’re in a non-humanoid form via a polymorph effect; **Effect** You unleash a bestial roar, attempting a single Intimidation check compared to the Will DCs of all enemies within 30 feet to impose the effects below. Though this activation has the command component, you can issue this command without the need for language.
> **Critical Success** The creature is frightened 2.
> **Success** The creature is frightened 1.

Consumable - [Dread Ampoule](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=686) (alchemical bomb)

> On a hit, the target becomes frightened 1, or frightened 2 on a critical hit.

*These Focus Spells can be acquired with the classes' [Multiclass Archetypes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?Category=4) but may require a very high level.

---

Honorable Mentions

[Antagonize](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1522) doesn't let you re-use Demoralize, but it may make the Frightened Condition last longer.

> When you successfully Demoralize a creature, its frightened condition can't decrease to less than 1 at the end of its turn until it either uses a hostile action against you or can no longer observe or sense you for at least 1 round.

[Remorseless Lash](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1028) will also extend your ability to keep Frightened on targets, if you have access to Hobgoblin (Uncommon) Feats.

> When you succeed at a melee weapon Strike against a frightened foe, that foe can’t reduce their frightened condition below 1 until the beginning of your next turn.

Comment: Also, Remorseless Lash can extend the duration of a Demoralize, or other fear effect, though you must be a hobgoblin or otherwise have access to hobgoblin feats. https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1028

Comment: There's also the Brutal Beating feat for ruffian rogues, which inflicts frightened 1 on any critical, and the Intimidating Strike feat for fighters, which inflicts frightened 1 if it hits (2 on a crit). These aren't the Demoralize action, and so work all the time.

Answer (score 11):

### Exemplary Finisher

Swashbucklers can do this at level 9, if they have the [Braggart](https://2e.aonprd.com/Styles.aspx?ID=2) style.

The Advanced Player Guide introduced Swashbucklers as a class. One of their key abilities is the ability to deal precision damage and other effects with Confident Finisher.  At level 9, a swashbuckler with the Braggart style gains an upgrade to their finisher which says:

> If the foe was temporarily immune to your Demoralize, their temporary immunity ends.

In order to trigger this ability, the swashbuckler needs to have panache, use an agile or finesse melee weapon (or agile/finesse unarmed weapon), and you used the Confident Finisher action.

Note that the braggart gains panache when they demoralize a foe, so having panache won't be a problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

Just want also to drop the rogue's [You're Next](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=553) feat, which allows you to demoralize a creature with a +2 circumstance bonus when you reduce an enemy to 0 hp has a reaction, and once you have legendary you can use it has a free action. If you are in a game with free archtypes you can get it by lvl4 with the rogue dedication, and picking Basic Trickery